# How might one begin to solve a Hamiltonian with a periodic kinetic energy term?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

So, suppose I'm considering a Hamiltonian similar to the form

$$\hat{H} = e^{iGx}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$$

Wolfram alpha gives me an (ugly) solution to this simple MWE Hamiltonian, but I wonder in general if

1. There exists a recipe to solve this type of system. Or, other theorems about the existence or character of solutions. One path that I've been working on for a complicated version of this Hamilton is to represent it in terms of G-vector zone raising or lowering operators, which gives solutions in G-vector space in terms of a difference equation but the terms get out of hand very quickly.

I see that the numeric solutions get a lot more interesting in the case with spinful and periodic kinetic energy terms, but the path to analytical solutions or analyzing the topology of the system is very murky to me :(

Comment: Not an answer because... I don't know, and you may already know about this. But you might want to take a look at Floquet's theorem and its use in deriving the Aulter-Townes effect. This is, of course, a _potential_ with the same time dependence, but maybe similar techniques can be used to solve this - where the kinetic term is the one with the periodic time dependence.

Comment: Bloch's theorem only depends on discrete translational invariance, so should still apply here. Express this in a momentum basis and I expect it will more or less come apart in your hands

Comment: What is the physical context here? What sort of system produces this kind of Hamiltonian?

Comment: Consider the dirac hamiltonian with a periodic $\sigma_z$ term, i understand this exists in hBN/graphene systems? Then, if you change the basis of your kinetic energy Hamiltonian to diagonalize the mass term, you will end up with terms like $sin(x)\frac{d}{dx}\sigma_{whatever}$. Then the "exchange splitting" is diagonal. I just don't know if this is a good path forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have at least a partial answer for the a modified version of the Hamiltonian above ($\hat{H}=-i e^{iGx}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$) but I still do not have any leads for 2).

So for this particular hamiltonian, expressing a solution $|\Psi\rangle$ in a momentum basis, I get $|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n |nG+k\rangle$. I will let $|n\rangle = |nG+k\rangle$. Acting the above hamiltonian on this gives:

$$\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (k+nG) |n+1\rangle=\sum_{n=-\infty-1}^{\infty-1} a_{n-1} (k+(n-1)G)|n\rangle$$.

Thus,

$$E a_n = (Gn+k-G)a_{n-1} $$

Which Wolfram Alpha solves as (where $(x)_n$ is the rising factorial)

$$ a_n = arb*\left(\frac{G}{E}
\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{G+k}{G}\right)_{n-1} $$

Rearranging, we get:

$$E = \frac{(Gn+k-G)a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$

(will update later)